# If $2^{k} + 1$ is prime, prove that $k$ has no other prime divisors than $2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to prove this by contradiction:

Assume $2^{k} + 1$ is prime.

By definition of odd number $2^{k} + 1$ is odd because $2^{k} + 1 = 2\cdot 2^{k-1} + 1$

Then $2^{k} + 1 \pmod{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$

Because $2^{k} + 1$ is odd, $2^{k}$ has to be even.
Let $k = ab$

I am stuck here, can someone help me?

Comment: $a+1 | a^n+1$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: How do I obtain that conclusion? I'm trying to manipulate the expression but I'm failing

Comment: @JOX take a look at my solution

Comment: @JOX $a^n+1 = (a+1)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}+\cdots + 1)$ when $n$ is odd (how? expand the RHS or identify it as a Goemetric progression with common ratio $(-a)$ .. do you know how to sum a GP?)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $k$ is odd then, $2^k+1=2^k-(-1)^k$, now use that $x^n-y^n $is divisible by $x-y$ to conclude.

**Proof that $x^n-y^n$ is divisible by $x-y$**:

We prove this by induction, $n=1$ follows, let $x^k-y^k$ be divisible by $x-y$.

Then $x^{k+1}-y^{k+1}=x(x^k)-x(y^k)+x(y^k)-y(y^k)=x(x^k-y^k)+y^k(x-y)$, which is divisible by $x-y$.

Hence by induction the result follows.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your last part, can I obtain that divisibility by manipulating the expression? I don't seem to remember that fact about x-y from before

Comment: @JOX look at the edited answer